# SSH tunnel from local machine to access a MySQL database using a jump host

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-subnet

My setup:

- EC2 instance within a private subnet that has a MySQL database
- EC2 instance within a public subnet that I use as bastion (jump host)

I'm able to login with SSH from the bastion host to the host in private subnet after following the instructions from https://digitalcloud.training/ssh-into-ec2-in-private-subnet/

But, I would like to access the MySQL database hosted on the instance that has the private subnet from local softwares (TablePlus, Tableau...).
I've been trying to do a SSH tunnel but without success.

Here's the command line I've been using:

`ssh -A ubuntu@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -L 3307:ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 -N -f -v`

This is my testing:

```
➜  ~ lsof -i4 -P | grep -i "listen" | grep 3307
ssh       95829 wild    8u  IPv4 0x35f42fb5d0e0a22b      0t0  TCP localhost:3307 (LISTEN)
➜  ~ nc -zv 127.0.0.1 3307
Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 3307 [tcp/opsession-prxy] succeeded!
➜  ~ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u my-username -p
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

And here's the response I'm getting on the server:

```
debug1: Connection to port 3307 forwarding to ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 3306 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3307 for ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59686 to 127.0.0.1 port 3307, nchannels 3
```

Comment: Do you want to access the MySQL database inside the private subnet using MySQL CLI from your computer?

Comment: `-L 3307:ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306` is almost certainly wrong, unless you actually have a machine with the name starting with `ubuntu@` somehow.

Comment: To clarify what *Anon Coward* said: `-L` takes a string in the form `PORT:HOST:PORT`. There's no need for `ubuntu@`.

Comment: Thanks, ubuntu wasn't needed in the command. I was able to setup the SSH tunnel.